# Лохина, горобина VS голубика, рябина

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

Завжди думала, що "*лохина*" - це український відповідник російської "*голубики*" (це такі фіолетово-голубі ягоди). У СУМ-20 є і [голубика](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19237&page=655), і [лохина](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48452&page=1527). Те саме стосується [рябини](http://sum.in.ua/s/rjabyna) та [горобини](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19541&page=664) (СУМ-11 і СУМ-20). На підтвердження теорії, що "голубика" та "рябина" російські слова, знайшла кілька джерел - [1](http://fakty.ua/163374-v-ukra-nsk-j-mov-smorodina-buva-t-lki-chorna-a-dlya-b-lo-chi-chervono-nsha-nazva-por-chki)-[2](http://dziga.meta.ua/8783933.video)-[3](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/yagodu-ukrayinskoyu-movoyu.-chastuna-2) (мабуть вони недостатньо переконливі порівняно з СУМ, тому й запитую). То як, все-таки, правильно сказати українською - *голубика* чи *лохина*, *рябина* чи *горобина*?

Comment: ще *буяхи* кажуть.

Comment: Буяхи я також чула, але воно, здається, менш поширене.

Comment: Цікаво, що Вікіпедія наразі має окремі статті [«Буяхи»](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Буяхи&oldid=21372971), [«Лохина»](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Лохина&oldid=22050390) і [«Vaccinium corymbosum»](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vaccinium_corymbosum&oldid=18195062) — хоча дехто [вважає, що це помилка](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Обговорення:Лохина&diff=prev&oldid=20761136&diffmode=source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зі статей, на які ви послалися у СУМ-20:

> [ЛОХИ́НА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48452&page=1527), и, ж. 1. Кущова рослина родини вересових із темно-синіми
>   їстівними ягодами.
>
> [ГОЛУБИ́КА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19237&page=655), и, ж., **розм**. 1. Те саме, що лохи́на.
>
> [ГОРОБИ́НА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19541&page=664), и, ж. 1. Дерево або кущ родини розових із яскраво-червоними або жовтогарячими ягодами, які ростуть гронами.
>
> [РЯБИ́НА](http://sum.in.ua/s/rjabyna), и, жін., **розм**., рідко. Те саме, що горобина.

Отже, в українській мові:

**Лохина** і **горобина** - літературні слова.

**Голубика** і **рябина** - розмовні слова.

Отже, якщо ви не пропаґуєте розмов літературною мовою, то у неформальному спілкуванні можна вживати будь-яке з цих слів.

У офіційних документах, наукових працях, літературних творах (якщо стилістика не вимагає використання розмовної мови) краще використовувати слова **лохина** і **горобина**.

Comment: «Рябина» ще й **рідко**.

Comment: @Sasha ну, "рідко" не відміняє словниковості, а ось "розм." відміняє літературність.